# Should I end every Function with semicolon

Tags: functions, formatting

```
Dynamic[ θSFG[λ2a_, θ2_, λ3a_, θ3_] := 
   ArcSin[(Sin[θ2/57.29577] / λ2a + 
           Sin[θ3/57.29577] / λ3a) / (1/λ2a + 1/λ3a)]*57.29577];
```

[image: Function]

```
Dynamic[θSFG[λ2a[λ2b, n2], θ2, λ3a[λ3b, n3], θ3]]
```

[image: Display]

If I add a semicolon after the function, the SFG will remain in blue, and it will display as shown (pic 2) instead of the single value that I want.
If I remove the semicolon, the single value will show, but I will get a NULL above my value. I am using a lot of functions so I will get a long long list of NULL. Is there any way to solve it?

Comment: Dynamic expression should never end with ";". The whole point of Dynamic is to update the expression on the screen at that spot. If you put ";" at end of any Dynamic, it means you are telling the front end not to display it. You are suppressing the output. You are adding ";" after Dynamic, not the function. I also do not understand why you wrap function definition with Dynamic. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: I just trying to create a grid where manipulating one variable in one cell will affect all other dependent variables in other cells and so on, do I need to add the semicolon after the function definition? The Nulls still appear though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are obviously a Mathematica beginner, I recommend that you not use `Dynamic` directly, but use [`Manipulate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Manipulate.html) which is designed to give beginners access to Mathematica's dynamic, interactive features without having to worry much about the niceties of `Dynamic`, at least for simple applications. Your application qualifies as simple enough.

```
lbl[s_] := Style[s, "TI"]
Manipulate[
  Grid[
    {{lbl["a" + "b"], a + b}, 
     {lbl["a*b"], a b},
     {lbl["plot"], Plot[PDF[NormalDistribution[a, b], x], {x, a - 3 b, a + 3 b}]}},
    Dividers -> All],
  {{a, 2}},
  {{b, Sqrt[2.]}}]
```

When this is first evaluated it looks like

[image: grid1]

If you were to change `a` to 10 and `b` to π, it would automatically update to

[image: grid2]

Note

It the 2nd and 3rd arguments to the `Manipulate` expression that specify the two two input fields at the top of the panel. This is the simplest kind of input control that can be specified. Many fancier controls are provided.